# Android app crashes on a link in an answer on Ask Ubuntu Meta

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app

I asked this question and a moderator (Seth) answered it: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14581/how-long-will-i-be-flag-banned-for

In it, he included the [link to the flag breakdown page](https://askubuntu.com/users/flag-summary/186134), which when tapped causes the Android App to crash.

Comment: For test only: [my flag summary on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/241919), and [edit my account link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/241919). **Edit:** partially repro'd here and also on meta.AU with Nexus 5, Marshmallow 6.0, app v1.0.73. The app didn't crash, but failed to open the page due to failure in parsing the link and instantly closing it. The link in this format is problematic: `users/text_instead_of_user_id/real_user_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce the crash in 1.0.83 and there's no historical changes to the part that would crash.

I am fixing the bug Andrew mentioned, where tapping the link does nothing because the user parsing failed.  Now it will kick the link to the browser.